# Reflection getDeclaredMethods() and class that is not in classpath

Tags: java, reflection

I am using reflection to get all methods from a specific class.

This class has references to class that not in my class path so I get an exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

On this:

```
Method methods[] = theClass.getDeclaredMethods();
```

Is it possible, somehow,to "skip" everything that is not in classpath?

Comment: What method are you using to load the class that doesnt resolve the dependencies? Usually, you will get the NoClassDefFoundError when loading the class, not fetching the methods.

Comment: i am using theClass=Class.forName()

Comment: ah, ok, i think i see your problem, i will post an answer with the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class.forName() will not load a class, whether it is or isn't in the classpath. It will only return a handle to a class that is already loaded.

A class gets loaded in one of 2 main ways:

1.)The class is referenced in the import statements(java.lang.* is imported automatically so every class in java.lang package is class-loaded from the start)

2.)A class is loaded using a call from a ClassLoader, in which case all of its dependencies are resolved. and loaded as well

So if you are trying to load a class outside of the classpath, or with dependencies outside the classpath, you need to subclass ClassLoader and tell it how to load your classes and their dependencies.

See ClassLoader specification here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html

Also, there are ready made subclasses of ClassLoader that may do what you want such as URL ClassLoader which will let you simply point the ClassLoader instance at the path, and load any classes in that path.

Comment: So if I need to inspect a class (just to get all the methods from it) and this class (or referenced classes that inside this class) I should use ClassLoader?

Comment: Correct, you can't inspect a class using reflections without first loading the class. If you just want to see method names without loading the class, you need a 3rd party java library capable of parsing .class files such as BCEL(Bytecode Engineering Library), but that may be more overhead than you are looking for.

Comment: Oh also, you may want to use javap, that java disassembler found with most java installs. it could also tell you the method names given the right arguments.

Comment: last questions: if the referenced class can't be found. can I still skip it and not to get that exception?

Comment: The class can't be loaded by a class loader if any of its referenced classes aren't resolvable, so you could always put in a try-catch block for NoClassDefinitionError, but you wont be able to view any methods from that class, at least not when using reflections. using one of the other techniques I mentioned, you still could. With BCEL, you could even extract one function from a class and load just that function.